# How do you update the task message links?

Tags: workflow, infopath, tasks

I have a Form Library that a feedback workflow is attached to.  The issue is, every task the gets generated, embeddes a link to the file for which the workflow is running.  Problem is, since this is a Browswer enabled form.  So when the person that the task is assigned to clicks on the link to the form, it tries to open in InfoPath Filler.  The desired behavior is to have it open in the browser.

Thoughts anyone?